# Reference Named Ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

In my Excel workbook, I've made a single cell a named range.  Instead of using vba to do this, I just went to `Formulas > Name_Manager > New` in Excel.  I now want to refer to this named range in a macro that I'm writing.  The macro will copy the color of a cell if that cell's background color matches that of my named range.

My macro currently works well when I refer to the cell's location as Range("S2") in the following code:

```
Trans_ECO_Row.Cells(, 13).Value = Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 14).Value
    If Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 14).Interior.Color = QueueSheet.Range("S2").Interior.Color Then
        Trans_ECO_Row.Cells(, 13).Interior.Color = Trans_Queue_Row.Cells(, 14).Interior.Color
    End If
```

However, I've named cell S2 `MGRColor` by going to `Formulas > Name_Manager > New` in Excel.  How can I replace S2 with `MGRColor` in my above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `Range()` function. The named range would be the function's only argument, surrounded by double quotes:

```
Range("MGRColor")
```

You can use this as you would any other range object:

```
Range("MGRColor").Value = ...
Range("MGRColor").Interior.Color = ...
' Etc
```